# R Diff function: Treat the first value of every group

Tags: r, dataframe, diff, plyr

so I´m having a little question regarding R´s `diff` function. Do I have a dataframe `df` of the following form:

```
ID  Var1   Difference
1    5        0
1    6        1
1    7        1
1    7        0
2    0        NA
2    2        2
2    4        2
2    7        3
```

whereas the `Difference` column was obtained by:

```
df %>% group_by("ID") %>%
       mutate(Difference = c(0, diff(Var1,
       lag = 1, differences = 1)))
```

However I´m not happy with the first value as 0 and especially, that the first value is reported as NA for every group. Instead I would like to have:

```
ID  Var1   Difference
1    5        5
1    6        1
1    7        1
1    7        0
2    2        2
2    2        0
2    4        2
2    7        3
```

so the first value of every group in `Difference` should be equal to the `Var1` value and the diff function should also take this value into account and calculate the second `Difference` value per group, taking into account this value.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
library(dplyr)                                                                                                            2L, 2L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
diffmod <- function(x) {
  c(x[[1]], diff(x))
}

df %>% group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Difference = diffmod(Var1),) %>% ungroup()

# A tibble: 8 x 3
     ID  Var1 Difference
  <int> <int>      <int>
1     1     5          5
2     1     6          1
3     1     7          1
4     1     7          0
5     2     0          0
6     2     2          2
7     2     4          2
8     2     7          3
```

Answer (score 1):

We could also use `lag` and get the difference (`-`)

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(ID) %>%
   mutate(Difference = Var1 - lag(Var1, default = 0))
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Var1 = c(5L, 
6L, 7L, 7L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 7L)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your logic you could do:

```
df %>%
 group_by(ID) %>%
 mutate(Difference = diff(c(0,Var1), lag = 1, differences = 1))
# A tibble: 8 x 3
# Groups:   ID [2]
     ID  Var1 Difference
  <int> <int>      <dbl>
1     1     5          5
2     1     6          1
3     1     7          1
4     1     7          0
5     2     0          0
6     2     2          2
7     2     4          2
8     2     7          3
```